# How do i remove this yellow line in AMP Sidebar?

Tags: html, amp-html

[yellow lien](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2oka.png)

Is it possible to remove this yellow line in sidebar? It appears only when i toggle it.

Comment: can you provide the code? I think it is an outline and you can remove it through CSS.

Comment: Hi, please provide more details about your question. Your question doesn't seem to be clear enough. Also, take a look at our guidelines on [how to ask?] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: @shreejalMaharjan share you code

Comment: I tried this code https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-sidebar/